# How do I update the property of a decimal data type in Microsoft SQL to change the number of decimals displayed?

Tags: sql, ssms

Recently I have been using Microsoft SQL for creating databases that are referred to using an excel document. There have been a number of instances when I needed to make a small changes to my tables and ended up "DROP"-ing all my current tables and re-creating them using an updated query. I understand you can use UPDATE to change the values of records within a table, but I'm looking to manipulate a data type so that I can change the number of decimals in one record of my tables from 2 to 3. Code for creating the table looks something like this:

CREATE TABLE WIRE_INDEX

```
--"Field"   "Data Type"    "Null or Not"
  (...
   ...
   DENSITY   decimal(18,2)  Not Null);
```

I don't know if the solution is something obvious, but I have been unable to find anything useful. I'm not sure know how to refer to the data type of a field in SQL.

When I populate the database I use numbers like 0.283 and 0.164, but when I SELECT the record I only get the first two decimals. I'd like the first 3 decimals to appear in the way I enter them into the table.

(edit didn't show up properly)

Comment: I believe you've already lost that precision and will probably need to re-insert them after modifying the column definition.

Comment: To avoid dropping and repopulating data, ALTER TABLE [tableName] ALTER COLUMN Density decimal (18,X) NOT NULL; http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alter-table-alter-column/

Comment: That worked. It updated my table to show the correct precision, but @TEEKAY you're correct I don't have the precision that I entered initially, but at least now I think can update each record with the correct data. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(not sure if I'm supposed to post my solution), but credit to TEEKAY and Apurav for answering my question. I used the code posted by Apurav which looks like this:

ALTER TABLE WIRE_INDEX
ALTER COLUMN DENSITY decimal(18,3) Not Null

When I pulled the table, using a SELECT statement the precision showed three decimal places, but I lost the precision of my input and had to re-enter my values using UPDATE. Not sure if this is more effective than just starting over, but it worked for me and now I know.